# strptime throws error when run in docker container

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

When I run

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('2020-01-15 09:20:00.00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
```

It prints out

```
2020-01-15 09:20:00+00:00
```

When I run a docker container with those exact same lines, it throws this error:

```
File "/vdp/base_functions.py", line 9, in <module>
j2lm@VB    |     print(datetime.strptime('2020-01-15 09:20:00.00+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
j2lm@VB    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
j2lm@VB    |     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
j2lm@VB    |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
j2lm@VB    |     (data_string, format))
j2lm@VB    | ValueError: time data '2020-01-15 09:20:00.00+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

How can that be?

Comment: Try `'2020-01-15 09:20:00.00 +0000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'` instead.

Comment: Can you add the python version of your local machine and that of in your container, also which docker image are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can that be?

I'm assuming you're developing snippets in some IDE, or `Jupyter` and than pasting it into the code that is run within a container. If so, make sure to use the same `venv` in your container image, that you are using to develop locally, to avoid issues like these, that can be tedious to debug.

If I use `python 3.7` I cannot reproduce the error, so you might solve the error just by using an up-to-date docker image and run the script with a more recent python version (Yours uses `3.6`).

[Here](https://realpython.com/python-versions-docker/) is a sophisticated guide on how to set up your Docker file in a way that you have full control over which version of `python` is used, that I found very helpful.